# Eclipse: Unable to build the project

Tags: eclipse

The project was not built due to "Resource already exists on disk: ''.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent

I am getting above error whenever I am trying to build the project.
Earlier the project was running fine, but all of sudden it stopped running and giving this error.

Eclipse version: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Helios Service Release 1
JRE: jdk1.5.0_22

Answer (score 23):

1. Try refreshing the project, clean and rebuild.
2. Right click on the error, click "Quick Fix" if this is enabled.
3. Right click on the error, click "Properties" for the details. Try to delete the resource in question from outside eclipse, refresh, clean and build.

Comment: Hi Nivas,Thanks for replying.... i tried all the steps...but its not helping.... and 'quick fix' button is disabled.

Comment: @Anshuman Did you try deleting the resource in question *outside* eclipse?

Comment: It seems to me, that the error then lies in a recent change in the code. Can you use your SCM to look for an older version of the software that was building well, and then create a diff to locate the faulty element?

Comment: Please help ..i am still having this problem

Comment: As @Zoltán Ujhelyi said, did you try do any recent changes? Can you trying rolling back that file(s)?

Comment: @Nivas Thank you. Deleting the .jar file resolved my issue. What cause this anyways?

Comment: @Jesse Eclipse sometimes is unable to delete resources for a bunch of reasons, so a "clean" build it does it not really clean sometimes. Deleting the resource (in this case the jar) makes sure eclipse rebuilds it (eg., copying the jar fresh etc)

Answer (score 7):

1. Exit Eclipse.
2. Delete all the java class files (These files located in /bin or like that).
3. Open Eclipse and wait a minute. The project will be rebuilt by Eclipse(auto).

Answer (score 1):

I had to go to **ST_SAMI\web\WEB-INF\classes** and delete **EVERYTHING** under the directory in question. Refreshed and cleaned project and all was well again.

**Version:** Helios Release (Also J2EE release for web developers)
**Build id:** 20100617-1415

Answer (score 1):

Project right click --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path and you have seen Project source paths.And attention please,

If you have more than one source, you should probably encountered this problem. You should examine each source.

Source click --> edit --> next --> and you seen exclusion patterns and inclusion patterns.

For example,
your directory path

```
source
  |
  \------ExDir
  |
  \------IncDir
```

You must select for inclusion only IncDir and select for Exclusion only ExcDir

- If you select for exclusion source Directory you encounter this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I placed the filter at Resource Filers sections which I removed and it started building properly.
Path - Right Click on project, Go into Properties, Select Resource Filters and remove any filter which is associated with bin folder.

[image]